# unable to dual boot ubuntu 12.04 LTS from windows boot manager

Tags: 12.04, lts

hi i have got stuck with a problem... i have installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS using windows installer wubi.. after the installation completed it asked for the reboot. i rebooted and for the 1st time ubuntu worked very fine. after shutting it down i cant boot it from windows boot manager. when i booted it a purple screen comes which turns into flickering screen.. so how to fix this... i have windows 7 64 bit os, radeon graphics...

Answer (score 0):

Windows boot manager doesn't detect non-Windows installations.

You must use grub.  If you want a user friendly method, try the boot-repair tool from Ubuntu's website (link below). Use the bootable image, and get it running on a handy USB or spare CD, since it only runs in a linux environment.

You can use this application to reinstall grub2, and repair many installation errors.  Try it out, and come back if you have trouble.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

If it is wubi and a video issue, Boot-Repair will not fix it. It is past the normal boot issue repairs that Boot-Repair can resolve and into video issues.

Boot-Repair can add nomodeset to standard grub, but I do not think it can do that with wubi. Alternative may be radeon.modeset=0.

From grub menu use e for edit, scroll down to linux line and change quiet splash to nomodeset. Depending on version of AMD, you probably need the proprietary drivers.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver